# How to show < and > correctly in output?

Tags: symbols, verbatim

I am trying to write some XML tags as part of my text but I can not get the < and > symbols to come out right in the output. What am I missing?

I have tried both `<tag>` and `\<tag\>`, the former results in `¡tag¿` and the later in error messages.

The document class is `report` and the environment is `document`.

Comment: If you have a lot of source code in your document, consider http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/867/syntax-coloring-in-latex.

Comment: this, and other features of xml, are addressed in [How to escape xml code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52780/579)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For formatting tags like `<tag>` prefer to wrap them into `\verb|<tag>|`.

Also, I'd recommend to create a custom command, like this (this will allow you to change the typesetting of all XML tags at once):

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\tag}[1]{\texttt{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{<}}#1\textbf{\textcolor{red}{>}}}}
\begin{document}
This is an XML \verb|<tag>| example.

This is an improved \tag{tag} example.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to have to type up more of these tags, the `listings` package may be well worth a try (employing colors for operators (or literals, or whatever) is tricky; if you'd like them, usually, one suggests the package `minted`, which unfortunately does not do inline stuff! catch 22!):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\begin{document}
      \lstinline[language=xml]!<tag>!  
\end{document}
```

Some remarks about the code:

1. `!` is a delimiter for the code that goes between its two instances: so, this should be a symbol that does not appear in the code (cf. `|` that appears in `\verb` command in [m0nhawk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9790/m0nhawk)'s solution). So,

   ```
   \lstinline<<tag>< % wrong
   \lstinline><tag>< % not wrong, but not what you want  
   \lstinline$<tag>$ % right 
   \lstinline+<tag>+ % right
   \lstinline|<tag>| % right
   ```
2. The delimiter cannot be this `[` unless you do the following:

   ```
   \lstinline[][<tag>[
   ```

   (What is happening is that, the `\lstinline` looks for an optional list of `key=value` pairs, when it first encounters `[`.)
3. I am posting this answer, mostly for the reason that, using `\verb`, you end up with different font family, which may well be your desire! In case, you'd like the same font family, this solution is open.

**Output:**

[image: lstinlinefun.png]

Comment: In this case I'm indifferent about the font or color, but it's good to know the options. It's just for a handful of tags in thi text and the font resulting from using `\verb` looks fine in the output so I'll stick to using that.

Comment: Sure thing! `:)` As I said, I am posting this mostly for variety, but also we can refer to this later on.