# Gibberish when using HTML labels with dot2texi

Tags: dot2texi

I'm attempting to use some of the psuedo-HTML markup in graphviz to style my nodes:

```
\documentclass{hitec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{dot2tex}[dot]
  digraph G {
    node [shape=plaintext]
    "Test"[shape=box,label=<
    <TABLE>
    <TR>
    <TD>
    </TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
    >];       
  }
\end{dot2tex}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When running this through either LaTeX or pdftex, I get output like this:

[image]

This happens regardless of if I have the graphviz code in line, or in an external file. Is this something unsupported by dot2tex, or do I have to escape the tags somehow?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112326/15925 help?  `<` and `>` are special characters in TeX, to help you with your Spanish.