# How to format xml?

Tags: formatting, xml

Hi I use the following LaTeX to ouput xml format data, however, there is no space before each line.

```
 \documentclass{minimal}
 \usepackage{etex},
 \begin{document}
 \medskip
 {\small\noindent
 \fbox{\begin{minipage}{6cm}
 <invoke operation="a3". . .>\\
 \hspace{3mm}<Handler>\\
 \ \ \ \ \ <operation="...." . . .>\\
 \ \ <Handler>\\
 </invoke>
 \end{minipage}}
 }
 \medskip
 \end{document}
```

The output is below:
[image]

However, I wish to output the format like this as there is some space align each line.
[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: You probably want either simply the `verbatim` environment, or a package for more sophisticated code listings, such as `listings` or `minted`. Edit: see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52780/how-to-escape-xml-code Spaces are preserved in `verbatim`, `lstlistings` and the like.

Answer (score 3):

[The `listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)<sup>1</sup> can help you out here, as suggested by Torbjørn T. in the comments. It's designed for typesetting code.

> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{listings}
> \lstset{language=XML,basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines=true}
>
> \begin{document}
> \begin{lstlisting}
> <invoke operation="a3" ...>
>   <Handler>
>     <operation="..." ...>
>   <Handler>
> </invoke>
> \end{lstlisting}
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> [image: It renders pretty well.]

Alternatives include the built-in `verbatim` environment, but that doesn't wrap lines quite as easily (you have to break them manually, instead of just setting `breaklines=true`). `listings` also offers syntax highlighting; it's quite configurable, but there is very basic highlighting by default, if you specify the language (as I have with `language=XML` above).

> ```
> \begin{lstlisting}
> <tag /> <!-- comment --> <![CDATA[foo]]>
> \end{lstlisting}
> ```
>
> [image: (tag unaffected, comment italicised, CDATA unaffected)]
>
> Note the italicisation of *`comment`*.

---

#### Footnotes

1. Which I am not affiliated with; I just like it.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I appreciate the welcome.